# JavaScript clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have a div become visible on a button click and have a setInterval append periods to show loading.  I would also like a button to clear that interval and hide the div that shows up.

here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4qx4r/4/

here's code:

```
function ProgressBar(){
   var div;
    var start = function(){
               var count = 0,
               div = $('#divNotification').show().text('Uploading').css('align','center'),
                   originalText = div.text(),
                   count = 0;

               var beginCount = setInterval(function(){
                   var newText = div.text() + '.';
                   div.text(newText);
                   count++;
                   if(count > 5){
                     div.text(originalText);
                     count =0;
                   }
                   console.log(count);
               },500)
       }
       var stop = function(){
           console.log('stop');
           div.hide();
           window.clearInterval(beginCount);
       }
   this.start = start;
   this.stop = stop;
}

var progressBar = new ProgressBar();
$('#btnStart').click(function(){
   progressBar.start();  
});
$('#btnStop').click(function(){
   progressBar.stop();
});
```

Currently when I click btnStop I get `cannot read property hide of undefined'.  How can I make this stop the interval and hide the div?

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `var beginCount` within a function, therefore that variable is only accessible within that function.

Try declaring that variable outside or simply just remove the `var` part.

I would add it next to `var div` declaration

Also you need to replace commas with semicolons and your `div` is not set to the object, try the following:

```
var count = 0;
div = $('#divNotification');
div.show().text('Uploading').css('align','center');
originalText = div.text();
count = 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qx4r/6/

Comment: Don't remove the `var`, you don't want to make it global. Simply move the declaration to the `ProgressBar` scope, next to the `div` declaration.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens agreed, just listing the options :).

Comment: since he is already using the ProgressBar to create object with start/stop methods the better way will be to save it as a property of the object.
use: this.beginCount instead var beginCount and it will be accessible from the stop method as well.

Answer (score 2):

this works: http://jsfiddle.net/W8ySn/3/

I separated the initial div assignment:

```
    div = $('#divNotification');
           var count = 0;                                      
           div.show().text('Uploading editor').css('align','center');
               originalText = div.text();
               count = 0;
```

Comment: That's *half* of the solution. The `clearInterval` is still not working, you can easily check this by commenting the `div.hide()` line. The `clearInterval` *should* stop the dots animation.

Comment: right, thanks. I moved the beginCount declaration outside the start function.